# Mongoose: Accessing Data in User-Model

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, pug

I am trying to access the data in my User-Model (using Express, Pug and Mongoose).

This is my schema:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userData: {
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: String
  },
  notes: [ String ],
  contacts: [{
    name: String,
    notes: [ String ]
  }],
  locations: [ String ]
});
```

This is my pug-template file:

```
each user in allUsers
  p #{user.userData.name}
```

My Route looks like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  if (app.locals.userData.name) {
    res.render('app', {
      currentUser: app.locals.userData,
      allUsers: User.find({})
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect('signup');
  }
});
```

Where could be my mistake?

The Browser shows a `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` error.

Comment: `User.find` returns a promise, and render will not wait for the promise to resolve. So you'll have to make sure, that `render` is only executed, after the result from the DB is available.

Comment: okay thanks. I have found the solution myself!!

Answer (score 1):

I had to use the callback function!!!

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    if (app.locals.userData.name) {
      res.render('app', {
        currentUser: app.locals.userData,
        allUsers: users
      });
    } else {
      res.redirect('signup');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You can even move `User.find` one level deeper after the `if` condition, as the `users` data is obviously only required `if (app.locals.userData.name)`. Avoids hitting the DB unnecessarily.